# Regex for string that validates for a number which may include decimal and for a particular length

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of length 5 which may or may not contain decimal place at runtime. I want to validate if the string is number and its length is 5.

input:

```
12340 - valid
123.4 - valid
123456 - not valid
123a5- not valid
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has showed no effort at all

Comment: You contradict yourself. A string of length 5 can never be exactly 12 long.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so we can say what's wrong with it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Run this code and test with all your inputs.It should solve your scenario.

```
String regex = "^[0-9.]{5}$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
String name= "123.4";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Comment: Answering such a low quality question is the same thing as saying that this level of, or rather lack of, quality is acceptable